# Plus and minus on accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Okay so I have a working accordion, which can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rW3KU/1/)

This is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {

        //Expand
        $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');

        //hide other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
});
```

obviously in there somewhere I need something along the lines of:

```
            $(this).next().slideUp('fast');
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
```

to make the content boxes close and the - get changed back to a + symbol but I have no idea how I would do this. Any help?

Comment: Hint: you have to check the symbol to see if it is a `+` or `-` first.

Comment: Assign `:after` or `:before` content using CSS.

Comment: Fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/rW3KU/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this with selectors, and I'm not entirely sure what is the most efficient, but one method you can do is grab the parent, select its siblings, and find the indicators.  Then setting it is easy.  Here is this method using your existing code:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BLg4b/)

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {

        //Expand
        $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        $(this).parent().siblings().find(".plusminus").text('+');
        $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');

        //hide other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
});
```

EDIT:

A much preferred method (in my opinion at least) would be to use a class with a pseudo-element.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BLg4b/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {

        //Expand
        $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        $(this)
          .closest('.accordion-wrap').addClass('active')
          .siblings().removeClass('active');

        //hide other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
});
```

then have a class like so

```
.accordion-wrap .accordion-toggle::after {
    content:'\000a0-';
}
.accordion-wrap.active .accordion-toggle::after {
    content:'\000a0+';
}
```

Comment: Works good, thank you! Is there anyway to get the minus to turn back into a plus when the toggle is clicked to close it? not just when another toggle is clicked on? Obviously changing slideDown to slideToggle so it can be closed...

Comment: @JoshuaBrand I didn't see that functionality in there, but you can just remove it on click after you have determined if it is open.

Comment: You cannot close the whole accordion with this solution.